# positivity of solution for Baouendi-Grushin operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sub-riemannian-geometry

Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^N = \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ with $m \geq 1$, $n\geq 0$, $\alpha \geq 0$ and $ Q=m+ n(\alpha +1)$.
Consider the following eqution

\begin{equation}\label{critical}
-(\Delta_{x} u+(\alpha+1)^2|x|^{2 \alpha} \Delta_{y} u)=u^{\frac{Q+2}{Q-2}},~~u\geq 0 ~\text{in } \mathbb{R}^N,
\end{equation}
where $u\in \mathbf{D}=\{v\in L^2| \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} (|\nabla_{x} v|^{2}+|x|^{2\alpha }|\nabla_{y} v|^{2}) d x d y< \infty\}.$  The partial differential operator
$\Delta_{\alpha}:=\Delta_{x} +|x|^{2 \alpha} \Delta_{y}$ is often called Baouendi-Grushin operator . I want to prove the non-trivial weak solution $u$ must be positive. That is, I have $u\geq 0$ ,$u\neq0$ and want $u>0$.
There exists a strong maximum  principle only for $C^2$-solutions, however, I can only prove a Hölder continuous result for such $u$. Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: If you can prove that $v\in \mathbf{D}\implies |v|\in\mathbf{D} $ then you can proof a weak maximum principle for $\Delta_\alpha$.

Comment: Do you have $u \geq 0$ and want $u>0$?

Comment: @Giorgio Metafune, yes, I want $u>0,$ unless $u\equiv0.$

Comment: @Liviu Nicolaescu, I'm sorry, but what I need is to show the non-negative non-trivial solution $u$ must be positive, i.e. $u>0.$